# Visual studio 2022 data source configuration wizard Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

[image]

Hello guys. I am getting an error like this when connecting to database in visual studio 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to this VS 2022 Note:

[image: Visual Studio 2022 Note]

You see that VS 2022 has x64 processes. Even if it seems that it warns about Access Database, it is not only about Access Db.

Developers can prefer to use historical OLE Db Providers to connect to SQL Databases. Specially when they want / need to use DataSet / DataTable etc. components.

Almost all x86 Processes (means project references, specially old ones) should be compatible with this situation when these want to use in Project.

Please Check that your reference dlls are x64 or not.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you created Windows Form App (**.NET framework**).

[image: Different types of apps in "Create a new project window"]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34991186)

Comment: @AlexzS.: There is no link to any solution. It's an image. Users with 1 rep can't embed the image themselves.